# Using Microsoft Face SDK for Bulging Effects

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to implement the effects like bulging of the face (for example concave and convex effects) to integrate when camera is on and also with saved images.

I tried using the `MeshWarp` static method provided by the `SDK`, but was unable to figure out the usage of it.

Can someone help me with explanation of how to use the mesh warp, `MLSD`? Some example would be of great help.

Comment: Which `MeshWarp` method is that? I can find no mention of it in MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from Microsoft.FaceSdk.Image.Warp Namespace reference.

> The MeshWarp algorithm accepts a source image and two 2-D arrays of
>   coordinates. The first array S, specifies the coordinates of control
>   points in the source image. The second array D, specifies their
>   corresponding positions in the destination image. Both S and D must
>   necessarily have the same dimensions in order to establish a
>   one-to-one correspondence. Refer to "2-pass warping", Chapter 7.5 in
>   Digital Image Warp, by George Wolberg.

The MLSD documentation in the Face SDK links to an outdated content page on MathWorks.com, the new link can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12249-moving-least-squares).

The Microsoft Face SDK is a relatively new project by Microsoft Research Asia, so documentation is a little scarce at this stage. Hopefully this gives you a little more information to go by.